# Why does it appear that you can indirectly modify a list

Tags: python, arrays

When I run the code below the output I get appears to show that the original array has been modified but as you can see the array itself isn't being changed

```
Arr = [["1","1","2"],["1","1","1"]]

def DoSomethingify(Arrs):
  for x in range(0, len(Arrs)):
    for y in range(0, len(Arrs[x])):
      if (Arrs[x][y] == "1"):
        Arrs[x][y] = "2"
      else:
        Arrs[x][y] = "1"
  print(Arrs)

for b in range(0, 9):
  DoSomethingify(Arr)

print(Arr)
```

Output:

```
[['2', '2', '1'], ['2', '2', '2']]
[['1', '1', '2'], ['1', '1', '1']]
[['2', '2', '1'], ['2', '2', '2']]
[['1', '1', '2'], ['1', '1', '1']]
[['2', '2', '1'], ['2', '2', '2']]
[['1', '1', '2'], ['1', '1', '1']]
[['2', '2', '1'], ['2', '2', '2']]
[['1', '1', '2'], ['1', '1', '1']]
[['2', '2', '1'], ['2', '2', '2']]
[['2', '2', '1'], ['2', '2', '2']]
```

Comment: It looks changed to me. Your final print statement certainly doesn't output the value you initially assigned to the array!

Comment: I *just* answered basically the same question, so closing as duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

The array itself has been changed, you changed it at these two lines:

```
Arrs[x][y] = "2"
Arrs[x][y] = "1"
```

The variable Arrs is still the original array, passing it to the function doesn't make a copy of the array

Comment: Ah that makes sense, if so why doesn't this work with other data structures like integers

Comment: @RamitJ It would work for integers too if they had any methods on them to change their value. But they don't.

Comment: Just the way python is designed. This doesn't just apply to functions, when you say `list2 = list1` this still doesn't make a copy of the array, changing one will change the other